# TypeORM: "No overload matches this call" error when using Repository.create with NestJS for one entity and dto but not another

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

## Problem

Hey so I've thrown my head against the wall enough times now to ask this question. I cannot find a solution anywhere and I'm very confused.

For some reason in the following piece of code, data in `this.customerAddressRepository.create(data)`is underlined with this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(entityLikeArray: DeepPartial<CustomerAddress>[]): CustomerAddress[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'CreateCustomerAddressDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<CustomerAddress>[]'.
      Type 'CreateCustomerAddressDto' is missing the following properties from type 'DeepPartial<CustomerAddress>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entityLike: DeepPartial<CustomerAddress>): CustomerAddress', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'CreateCustomerAddressDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<CustomerAddress>'.ts(2769)
```

As far as I can see. The implementation of the foreign key ID's in CustomerAddresses are similar to the restaurant foreign key in Menus. Can anyone please tell me what's going on? I'm hard stuck.

## Code

### I have these 2 entities:

```
import { MenuItem } from 'src/menu-items/entities/menu-item.entity'
import { Restaurant } from 'src/restaurants/entities/restaurant.entity'
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm'

@Entity('menus')
export class Menu {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  name: string

  @JoinColumn({ name: 'restaurant_id' })
  @ManyToOne(() => Restaurant, restaurant => restaurant.menus)
  restaurant: Restaurant

  @OneToMany(() => MenuItem, menuItem => menuItem.menu, { cascade: true, eager: true })
  menuItems: MenuItem[]
}
```

```
import { AddressDetail } from 'src/address-details/entities/address-detail.entity'
import { Customer } from 'src/customers/entities/customer.entity'
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, JoinColumn } from 'typeorm'

@Entity('customer_addresses')
export class CustomerAddress {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @JoinColumn({ name: 'customer_id' })
  @ManyToOne(() => Customer, customer => customer.addresses)
  customer: Customer

  @JoinColumn({ name: 'address_id' })
  @ManyToOne(() => AddressDetail, { eager: true })
  address: AddressDetail
}
```

### And these 2 respective create functions in their services:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { CreateCustomerAddressDto } from './dto/create-customer-address.dto'
import { UpdateCustomerAddressDto } from './dto/update-customer-address.dto'
import { CustomerAddress } from './entities/customer-address.entity'
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices'

@Injectable()
export class CustomerAddressesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(CustomerAddress)
    private readonly customerAddressRepository: Repository<CustomerAddress>,
  ) {}

  async create(data: CreateCustomerAddressDto): Promise<CustomerAddress> {
    const customerAddress = this.customerAddressRepository.create(data)
    return this.customerAddressRepository.save(customerAddress)
  }
}
```

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common'
import { CreateMenuDto } from './dto/create-menu.dto'
import { UpdateMenuDto } from './dto/update-menu.dto'
import { Menu } from './entities/menu.entity'
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { RpcException } from '@nestjs/microservices'

@Injectable()
export class MenusService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Menu)
    private readonly menuRepository: Repository<Menu>,
  ) {}
  async create(data: CreateMenuDto): Promise<Menu> {
    const menu = this.menuRepository.create(data)
    return this.menuRepository.save(menu)
  }
}
```

### And here are the modules:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { MenusService } from './menus.service'
import { MenusController } from './menus.controller'
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { Menu } from './entities/menu.entity'

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Menu])],
  controllers: [MenusController],
  providers: [MenusService],
})
export class MenusModule {}
```

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { CustomerAddressesService } from './customer-addresses.service'
import { CustomerAddressesController } from './customer-addresses.controller'
import { CustomerAddress } from './entities/customer-address.entity'
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([CustomerAddress])],
  controllers: [CustomerAddressesController],
  providers: [CustomerAddressesService],
})
export class CustomerAddressesModule {}
```

I don't know what to do. I've looked everywhere, but I can see no discrepancies.

Comment: can you provide your Menu module?

Comment: Added both modules to the end of my post :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```js
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Menu]),
```

in your imports module

Comment: Sorry it seems I'm a stressed out idiot. Those are the modules for my gateway. I've just udpdated the post with the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataCustomerAddress: CustomerAddress = data;
const customerAddress = this.customerAddressRepository.create(dataCustomerAddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

typeorm needs to know which entities you are dealing with, so in both modules you need to add the entities:

```
  import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
  import { MenusService } from './menus.service'
  import { MenusController } from './menus.controller'
  import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
  import { CustomerAddress } from './entities/customer-address.entity'
  import { Menu } from './entities/menu.entity'

  @Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Menu, CustomerAddress])],
    controllers: [MenusController],
    providers: [MenusService],
  })
  export class MenusModule {}
```

```
  import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
  import { CustomerAddressesService } from './customer-addresses.service'
  import { CustomerAddressesController } from './customer-addresses.controller'
  import { CustomerAddress } from './entities/customer-address.entity'
  import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
  import { Menu } from './entities/menu.entity'

  @Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Menu, CustomerAddress])],
    controllers: [CustomerAddressesController],
    providers: [CustomerAddressesService],
  })
  export class CustomerAddressesModule {}
```